# Can "nemo" be an adjective?

Tags: vocabulary, translation-explanation

I subscribe to a "Latin word of the day" email, which sends me a random vocabulary word and an example sentence every day. Last night's email had this:

> *pecco*, to sin.
>   *Nemo accusator caret culpa; omnes peccavimus.*

The translation seems to be "no accuser is free from guilt; we have all sinned".

But I'm confused by the *nemo* at the beginning. I'm used to *nemo* being a noun; if I were translating this sentence into Latin, I would have used *nullus* here instead.

Is it correct to use *nemo* as an adjective like this? If so, what's the difference in meaning—that is, what would be different if I used *nullus* instead here?

Answer (score 4):

While it's mostly used as a noun, *nemo* may rarely be found as an adjective. The Vulgate reports the following phrase by Jesus:

> Ait autem: Amen dico vobis, quia nemo propheta acceptus est in patria sua.
>
> (Lucas 4:24)

The Italian [Treccani Vocabulary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nemo-propheta-in-patria/) translates the sentence with *nemo* as an adjective: *nessun profeta è gradito in patria*, "no prophet is welcome in ther own land".

Given that in the comments it has been suggested the above sentence may not be the best example, here's a better one from Cicero:

> Nemo doctus umquam dixit mutationem consilii esse constantiam.

Perhaps one could translate this as "no one that has been instructed ever said...", but the most natural meaning here is "no man of culture", with *doctus* being a substantive and *nemo* an adjective - see the [entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=doctus) for *doctus* in L&S.

---

I can't back this up, but since *nemo* is the contraction of *ne*+*hemo* (where *hemo* is an archaic form of *homo*), I guess it could be exploited to highlight the *humanitas* involved - as in, *nullus* works for objects and animals as well, *nemo* does not. But really, there isn't much difference.

Comment: I would actually read that *nemo* as a noun: "Nobody is accepted as a prophet in their own land."

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: this kind of thing is known as _nomina coniuncta_. It does not, as far as I can think, have an actual English equivalent, so we interpolate words to make the meaning in Latin clear in the English, as you and Sumelic  indicate.

Comment: +1. I agree that the example looks ambiguous, but the general answer is backed by [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnemo), see meaning II.A.

Comment: The form of this verse in Greek, "Ἀμὴν λέγω ὑμῖν ὅτι οὐδεὶς προφήτης δεκτός ἐστιν ἐν τῇ πατρίδι αὐτοῦ" might be relevant to the grammar of the Vulgate version, since the Latin seems to be a word-for-word translation. I don't know whether "προφήτης" could be interpreted as anything but the subject there.

Comment: @Rafael Can you post the support found in L&S in another answer? A separate argument in support of the same conclusion should be given as a new answer.

Comment: @sumelic: If I knew something of Greek I would ask a question about the role of _propheta_ and thus of _nemo_ in that Vulgate passage. Please consider posting one yourself!

Comment: It is indeed very hard to prove! Ideally, you'd have [nemo + noun that normally isn't adjectival] with a  verb that isn't a copula and doesn't typically invite apposition. But, even then, aren't [substantive noun + apposition] and [attributive noun + substantive noun] indistinguishable in Latin and Greek?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva. The corresponding word for _nemo_ in Greek is [οὐδείς](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ou%29dei%2Fs&la=greek), which is an adjective.